# SELECT the same date as in the datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a datepicker with the format `d/m/Y`:

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="single_cal4" class="form-control has-feedback-left" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status4">
```

If the date is changed I want to run an SQL statement that needs to select the `id` from the database WHERE the year is the same year as the selected year in the datepicker.

Does someone know how I can run an SQL statement that runs an WHERE with the selected year from the datepicker?

Here is my SQL statement:

```
$sql = SELECT id FROM `trans` WHERE user_id='". $_SESSION['user_id'] ."' AND year(date) = ";
```

Comment: You will probably need ajax/jquery for this. Basically `onchange` of the datepicker, perform an ajax post/get to another page that will return the results of the query, and then use use javascript/jquery to update the page you are on with the data you just received.

Comment: You may be able to find more information about this at [jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

Comment: Your question is not clear! if you want to write a sql statement you just did it in your example above. However if your want to send the request immediately after the input is changed so you can use Ajax...

Comment: Ok, I understand. But with: `#single_cal4` I can select the full date. The sql statement will look like year(date) = `6/7/2017`. But to run the statement I only need the year.  How can I only select the year of `#single_cal4`

Answer (score 0):

Since your supplied date is not the right format for SQL's `YEAR()` function, I would just use `substr` on the input as below:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['date'];);
$year = substr($date, -4);
$sql = "SELECT id FROM `trans` WHERE user_id=". $_SESSION['user_id'] ." AND YEAR(date)=".$year;
```

Dont forget to sanitize the input.